# how to make an sql file copied to the server work

Tags: ubuntu, php, mysql

I am trying to create a login page on my ubuntu server.
I have Apache2, php, and mysql installed and running.
I downloaded a sample PHP MySQL Login System including a users.sql file.
Is there a way to make this file work with MySQL or is it necessary to generate a new file?
If so, how..? Here is the code from the users.sql file.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.1.14
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Apr 28, 2017 at 02:20 PM
-- Server version: 5.6.17
-- PHP Version: 5.5.12

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `demo`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Thanks for help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to load that file would be by using MySQL directly from the command line. If you already have PHPMyAdmin installed you may use it to load the file if you prefer.

From the command lie with your server running switch to the directory where that file resides. You'll need to know the path to your MySQL executable so you may call it. It may be something like:

```
/usr/bin/mysql
```

You would use it like this to actually load the file:

```
/usr/bin/mysql -uroot -p < name_of_the_file.sql
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. I am getting an error with this command: `mike@userver:/var/www/html$ /usr/bin/mysql -uroot -p < users.sql
Enter password: 
ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 29: No database selected` The file in question is present: `mike@userver:/var/www/html$ ls
07_21_2020     config.php    loginform   overflow            storage      welcome.php
82020          dist          login.php   register.php        **users.sql**
bootstrap.css  double_arrow  logout.php  reset-password.php  users-table`  Any suggestions ? @Dave Thanks, Mike
`

Comment: I'm assuming you have already created a database and, for the sake of argument, we'll call it `demo` as reference in what you posted originally. Edit users.sql and on the line above the first `create table` add a new line that contains `use demo;`.

Comment: Dave, ran the command to load the users.sql file and it seemed to work. After issuing the command I was returned to the msql prompt.
The problem starts with the config.php file. If I comment out the require_once "config.php"; line the login pages will load in the browser as normal, although they will not process any input. login.php will not load at all with the config.php included. Browser returns, This page isn’t working userver is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500 . config.php file code in next comment. @Dave

Comment: `<?php
/* Database credentials. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
define('DB_SERVER', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mdd');
define('DB_NAME', 'demo');
 
/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
 
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>`